# Multithreaded Searchbox

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a custom searchbox control (that accesses my database in a very custom way).  The search method may take upwards of 3 seconds to complete, which causes awful lags. To fix this, I started running the search method on a different thread. Every time the text is changed in the textbox, a new thread is created that runs the search and populates a datagrid, and because people type faster than the search runs, I end up with about 10 search threads all running at the same time.

The problem is if the first search takes longer than the second, the second (most current) search populates the datagrid followed by the first (not current) search because it took longer to complete. This means the search data no longer matches what's in the search field.

I need a way to 'cancel' all the threads except the most recent one.

I have tried this code to cancel the most previous search with no luck.

```
System.Threading.Thread searchThread;
public void RunSearch()
{
    if (searchThread != null)
    {
        if (searchThread.IsAlive)
        {
            searchThread.Abort();
        }
    }
    searchThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(RunSearchThread));
    searchThread.Start();
}
```

The `RunSearch()` method is what's called on the TextChanged event.

The `RunSearchThread()` method executes the search. It also catches the ThreadAbortException and ends the method.

Doing it this way still causes weird lags in the searches.  I'm assuming this is because it's waiting for the thread to abort before the main thread can continue.

Is there a better way to 'cancel' all but the most recent thread? If not, is there a better way to do a searchbox?

Comment: If user is idle for sometime then start a search. Use timer for this. Start thread in that timer, so that you can avoid multiple threads upto an extent

Comment: I think you may be right; the Abort method could be blocking. Perhaps you might want to launch the "aborter" on a thread of its own. Aside from the lag issue, not sure how robust any of this would be. Have you considered using a "high water mark" technique - assign a sequence number to each request, and only populate the control when the result comes back bearing the last-assigned sequence number?

Comment: Take a look at Rx.Net. The `.Throttle()` monad is pretty good for doing the "idle" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running on `TextChanged`, have a binding with delay on a property in your viewmodel. Then your search will only run after x milliseconds of inactivity.

**View:**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Delay=1000" />
<Datagrid ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" ... />
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private string _searchText
public string SearchText
{
    get{...}
    set
    {
        if(_searchText != value)
        {
            _searchText = value;
            RunSearch();
        }

}

public ObservableCollection<...> SearchResults { get; set; }

private void searchThreadCompleted(results)
{
    SearchResults = results;
}
```